# python Regular Expression skipping stings it should not

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a regex where I want to skip `.do` string but allow `.doc` string.

What I have is `\.do`. However it also skips `.doc` files.  Is there away to only capture `.do` and ignore strings that contain `.doc` or `.docx`

so `\.do` should match `mike.do` but not `mike.doc` Currently it matches both.

https://regex101.com/r/nBL5rg/2

Comment: You can try using a word boundary `\b`: `r"\.do\b"`

Comment: that worked.  thanks.  getting into regex was unfamiliar

Comment: An alternative you can try is `\.do(?!\S)` to make sure anything except a whitespace after .do will be rejected.